# Get XML child node value with dynamic parent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a `Process` table in SQL Server like this:

[image]

`workflowXML` column has values like this:

```
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" 
      xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" 
      xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" 
      xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" 
      id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn">
     <bpmn:process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
         <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1rin5au">
             <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1q36672</bpmn:outgoing>
         </bpmn:startEvent>   
         <bpmn:userTask id="UserTask_038517r" name="addRequest">
             <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_1q36672</bpmn:incoming>
             <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0dpq0oe</bpmn:outgoing>
         </bpmn:userTask>      
         <bpmn:serviceTask id="ServiceTask_17e1u09" name="checkRequest">
             <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_1q36672</bpmn:incoming>
             <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1233bp0</bpmn:outgoing>
         </bpmn:serviceTask>        
     </bpmn:process>    
</bpmn:definitions>
```

I need a SQL query to get `id` node that `incoming` value be equal with `outgoing` value in `bpmn:startEvent` node.

I test this subquery:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL' AS bpmn) 
select 
    p.workflowXML.value('(bpmn:definitions/bpmn:process/bpmn:userTask/bpmn:incoming)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from 
    Process as p
```

But this code only returns result for `bpmn:userTask`. I used other subquery:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL' AS bpmn) 
select 
    p.workflowXML.value('(bpmn:definitions/bpmn:process/../bpmn:incoming)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from 
    Process as p
```

But it returns `null`.

My query is like this:

```
declare @SequenceFlow nvarchar(max)
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL' AS bpmn) 
select @SequenceFlow = 
(
SELECT p.workflowXML.value('(/bpmn:definitions/bpmn:process/bpmn:startEvent/bpmn:outgoing)[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
from Process as p
where ID = 1
)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL' AS bpmn) 
select p.workflowXML.value('(bpmn:definitions/bpmn:process/../bpmn:incoming)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
from Process as p
where p.workflowXML.value('(bpmn:definitions/bpmn:process/../bpmn:incoming)[1]','nvarchar(max)') = @SequenceFlow
```

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output given the above sample data?

Comment: @har07 For sample data, result is id="ServiceTask_17e1u09" and id="UserTask_038517r"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `*` to reference element of arbitrary name :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL' AS bpmn) 
select t.c.value('@id','nvarchar(max)')
from Process as p
    cross apply p.DiagramXML.nodes('bpmn:definitions/bpmn:process/*') AS t(c)
where t.c.value('bpmn:incoming[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = @SequenceFlow
```

Notice that `cross apply` is used to shred XML data at child of `bpmn:process` element level. This allows the query to return multiple rows from single XML column data.